# Open Google Maps or Apple Maps in iPhone or Other Mobile Device via Browser

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, mobile, apple-maps

I have links that go to Google Maps, but now since Apple updated to their own service my iPhone goes to the Google Maps website.  Is there a way in HTML to show the [Apple Maps link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html), when it's iOS6, and show the Google Maps link for all other devices.  I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is even easier than that and won't require any conditional statements:

- When clicked from an iOS6 device, links to
  [maps.apple.com/maps?q=cupertino](http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=cupertino) are opened in Apple's native
  mapping application.
- But on other mobile devices and computers, it redirects to Google
  Maps (at [maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino)) instead.

So at this point, all you need to do is include the Apple Maps link and it should work as expected on non-iOS devices.

---

I mentioned this in a [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160049/same-parameters-for-apple-maps-and-google-maps-api) that also touches on whether the same parameters can be used.

Comment: Thanks that's awesome.  I cam confirm under Mavericks it launches the Mapp app and on older OS Xs it opens google maps in a web page.