# Same parameters for Apple Maps and Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, compatibility, apple-maps

On iOS 6 devices like the iPhone and iPad, as well as the latest Mac's, a link to [maps.apple.com/maps?q=cupertino](http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=cupertino) is opened in Apple's native mapping application.

On non-Mac computers and other devices, it leads to [maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino) instead.

This is a welcome functionality for developers, however, is Apple's API supported by Google Maps?

In other words, do all of the [following Apple Maps parameters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1) translate perfectly to something in Google Maps on the web?

```
q=      The query parameter.
near=   The location part of the query.
ll=     The latitude and longitude points for the map center point.
sll=    The latitude and longitude points from which a business search should be performed.
spn=    The approximate latitude and longitude span.
sspn=   A custom latitude and longitude span format used by Apple.
t=      The type of map to display.
z=      The zoom level.
saddr=  The source address, which is used when generating driving directions
daddr=  The destination address, which is used when generating driving directions.
```

Or is it best to not use some of these on websites?

Answer (score 1):

The only negative part now is that https://maps.apple.com displays a certificate error on an Apple device but goes straight to google on a non-Apple device. Sure you can link directly to http://maps.apple.com but HTTPS everywhere is the new mantra isn't it?